Как загрузить файл в Google Colab?
Он выдает такую ошибку - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Vika\OneDrive\Документы\Ophrys.csv'

Для загрузки любых файлов из локальной файловой системы в текущую рабочую директорию Colab можно воспользоваться опцией Upload в верхней части панели менеджера файлов. Для загрузки файлов напрямую в поддиректорию нужно: Кликнуть на три точки, появляющиеся при наведении курсора на каталог. Выбрать опцию Upload.
